# Run remote command from script

Tags: linux, bash, macos, ssh, sh

I need to run a shell script from within jenkins, to commit changes after making the build. Deploying build to remote server is not a problem, so the new build is there. All I need to do is just commit it.

For that I need to login with ssh to that remote server using shell script, and so far it is okay:

```
#!/user/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh myusername@url
expect "password:"
send "mypassword\r"
interact
```

So now when I am logged in, I want to run a few commands: `cd /path/to/repository; svn commit -m "Some change log"`

I tried something like:

```
#!/user/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh -o "LocalCommand cd /path/to/repository" myusername@url
expect "password:"
send "mypassword\r"
```

But it just don't work, as I have no idea how to do it.

If anyone know how to do it, please let me know.

The remote server is running on **linux**, and the jenkins on **osx**.

Comment: You should setup ssh keys so you do not need to use `expect` to pass them along.  Then just run a regular `ssh -t /command/to/run arg1 arg2` from a shell script.

Comment: Thanks, but I found solution with `expect`

Answer (score 0):

I found solution just with expect:

```
#!/user/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh myusername@url
expect "password:"
send "mypassword\r"
expect "some server prompt"
send "cd /path/to/repository\r"
send "svn commit -m 'Some change log'\r"
```

**EDIT:**

This solution seems to work from time to time only. I mean commiting changes.